# html table as sql string split and save in sql table

Tags: html, sql, html-table, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I have an artikel description saved in an artikel table which I want to split and insert into sql table

```
    SELECT [cBeschreibung]
    FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tartikel]
    where cArtNr = 'TF90062750'
```

The description always looks like the following.

```
<b>Hohe Performance</b><br \><b>Systemoptimierung mit einem Klick</b><br \><b>Übertaktungs- und Energiesparfunktionen, digitale Leistungsregelung, konfigurierbare Lüftersteuerung und flexible Netzwerk- und Audioeinstellungen</b><br \><br \>Komplexes Systemtuning mit einem Klick: Die 5-fach-Optimierung von ASUS macht aus Ihrem System einen intelligenten PC. Wichtige Parameter werden in Echtzeit dynamisch optimiert. Sie profitieren von exzellenter CPU-Leistung, Energieeinsparungen im Alltag, besonders stabiler digitaler Spannungsregelung und leiser Systemkühlung. Und jetzt werden auch Netzwerk- und Audioeinstellungen an Ihre Anwendungen angepasst. Mit der 5-fach-Optimierung ist Ihr PC für alles gerüstet – von Gaming über Unterhaltung bis hin zu Produktivitätsanwendungen.<br \><br \>- Spiele laufen flüssig, mit hoher Leistung, priorisierter Bandbreite und lebendigem Sound.<br \>- Die Lüfter bleiben bei geringer Auslastung flüsterleise und sorgen beim Gaming für maximale Kühlleistung.<br \>- Filme werden ruckelfrei wiedergegeben.<br \>- Energieeinsparungen senken die Stromkosten.<br \><br \><b>Lüftersteuerung für maximale Kühlleistung und minimale Geräuschentwicklung</b><br \><b>Fan Xpert 3</b><br \>Fan Xpert 3 ist die Schaltzentrale für drei- und vierpolige CPU- und Gehäuselüfter. Die Lüftersteuerung erfasst die Eigenschaften aller Lüfter und nimmt für jeden einzelnen angepasste Einstellungen vor, die sich an den mit Sensoren gemessenen Temperaturen in verschiedenen Zones des PCs orientieren. Auf diese Weise wird für jeden Lüfter die optimale Balance zwischen Kühlleistung und geringem Betriebsgeräusch gefunden. Fan Xpert 3 unterstützt den hardwareseitigen PWM/DC-Kombimodus bei CPU- und Gehäuselüftern. Es kann die Drehzahl des CPU-Lüfters sogar bis unter den Standard-Mindestwert verringern, sodass er besonders leise und stromsparend läuft.<br \><br \><b>Preisgekröntes UEFI-BIOS</b><br \>Das eleganteste grafische BIOS mit Maussteuerung ist jetzt noch ansprechender. Unerfahrene Anwender und routinierte Overclocker finden sich mit dem einfachen EZ-Modus und dem erweiterten Modus gleichermaßen zurecht.<br \><br \><b>Erweiterte</b><br \><b>RAM-Übertaktungsmöglichkeiten</b><br \>Jetzt können Sie Ihren Speicher auf bis zu 3.200 MHz übertakten. Unser exklusives T-Topology-Design schafft überragende Übertaktungsmöglichkeiten unter Volllast und minimiert dabei Störungen und Signalreflektionen. Die Speicherkanäle verlaufen in gleichem Abstand zur CPU und bieten so eine besonders ausgewogene Steuerung über mehrere Speichermodule und eine insgesamt verbesserte Speicherkompatibilität.<br \><br \><b>Schnellere Festspeicher mit</b><br \><b>SATA Express</b><br \>SATA Express erreicht eine Datenübertragungsrate von bis zu 10 Gbit/s mit zwei PCIE-2.0-Lanes und ist damit bereit für die Anforderungen der Zukunft. Aktuelle SSDs erreichen bis zu 550 MB/s und nähern sich damit der Obergrenze von SATA mit 6 Gbit/s. Als Verbindungsstandard der nächsten Generation macht SATA Express Ihr System bereit für die Zukunft und ist dabei rückwärtskompatibel zu bis zu zwei SATA-Laufwerken.<br \><br \><b>Ein schnelleres System mit M.2</b><br \>Mit der doppelten nativen Bandbreite von PCI Express 2.0 unterstützt M.2 Datenübertragungsraten von bis zu 10 Gbit/s. Dies empfiehlt sich insbesondere für das Laufwerk des Betriebssystems und beschleunigt so den gesamten PC. Die Unterstützung für Intel® Rapid Storage Technology gewährleistet einen noch schnelleren Datenzugriff, schneller reagierende Anwendungen und eine Reaktivierung aus dem Ruhezustand in wenigen Sekunden.*<br \>* Weitere Hinweise zur Unterstützung von Intel® Rapid Storage Technology finden Sie in den technischen Daten der einzelnen Modelle"<br \><br \><b>Die Geschwindigkeit von Thunderbolt™2 schon heute</b><br \>Die Karten der ThunderboltEX-II-Serien von ASUS sind die ersten von Intel® zertifizierten Thunderbolt™-2-Erweiterungskarten. Damit können Sie Ihr System jederzeit auf Thunderbolt 2 aufrüsten. Sie profitieren von bidirektionalen Übertragungsraten von bis zu 20 Gbit/s – das ist das Vierfache von USB 3.0! Erleben Sie Filme mit unglaublichen Details auf aktuellen 4K/UHD-Monitoren, und nutzen Sie gleichzeitig Festspeichergeräte mit hohem Bandbreitenbedarf.<br \><br \><b>Schneller reagieren, besser punkten</b><br \><b>Turbo App</b><br \>Das Geräusch feindlicher Schritte in der Ferne. Eine Drehung und eine gezielte Salve – Sie waren wieder einmal schneller. Als Gamer wissen Sie, dass man nur mit schnellen Reaktionen gewinnt. Deshalb benötigen Sie ASUS Turbo App – ein intuitives Tuning-Panel, das Ihnen bei Ihren Lieblingsspielen einen entscheidenden Vorteil verschaffen kann. Übertakten Sie die CPU, priorisieren Sie die Datenübertragung von Spielen, und optimieren Sie die Audioeinstellungen für klaren Klang und verständliche Unterhaltungen im Spiel. Nur der Schnellste gewinnt. Rüsten Sie sich deshalb mit Turbo App.<br \><br \><b>Makelloser Sound</b><br \><b>versetzt Sie mitten ins Spiel</b><br \><b>Crystal Sound 2</b><br \>Crystal Sound 2 optimiert nach Ihren Vorstellungen im Handumdrehen die Audioeinstellungen für Spiele, Gespräche, Filme und Ihre Lieblingsmusik. Die Abschirmung, der professionelle Leitungsaufbau und die hochwertigen Komponenten, darunter japanische Audio-Kondensatoren und Operationsverstärker (OpAmps), sorgen für außergewöhnliche Klarheit und Klangtreue. Entdecken Sie Klangqualität in einer neuen Dimension und den entscheidenden Vorteil im Spiel.<br \><br \><b>Doppelter Vorteil für Gamer</b><br \>Zwischen Sieg und Niederlage liegen manchmal nur Millisekunden. Deshalb sind Mainboards von ASUS mit hochmoderner Netzwerktechnologie ausgestattet, die Ihnen den entscheidenden Vorteil verschafft.<br \><br \><b>Turbo LAN</b><br \>Turbo LAN mit der Traffic-Shaping-Technologie cFosSpeed minimiert Verzögerungen und überzeugt mit einer intuitiven Oberfläche. Reduzieren Sie Verzögerungen ohne Netzwerkkenntnisse um einen Faktor von bis zu 1,45. Und für Experten bietet der erweiterte Modus umfassende Einstellmöglichkeiten.<br \><br \><b>Ihr PC, Ihre Welt</b><br \>Die ASUS HomeCloud überwindet Grenzen. Sie können aus der Ferne auf Ihren PC zugreifen, Multimedia-Dateien streamen und alle Ihre Daten verwalten – von jedem Ort aus, unabhängig vom Speicherort. Nutzen Sie die integrierte Wake-on-WAN-Funktion, um Ihren PC mit einem Mobilgerät zu aktivieren und zu steuern – und zwar jederzeit und überall. Sie können sogar Ihre Festplatte in eine private Cloud verwandeln und sich damit von den Speicherbeschränkungen der Cloud-Dienste unabhängig machen. Mit der HomeCloud wird Ihr PC das Tor zur Ihrer Welt.<br \><br \><b>Jederzeit und überall volle</b><br \><b>Kontrolle mit Remote GO!</b><br \>Mit Remote GO! haben Sie die volle Kontrolle über Ihren PC, auch wenn Sie unterwegs sind. Greifen Sie auf Dateien zu, die Sie zu Hause vergessen haben, oder arbeiten Sie am PC, während Sie unterwegs oder in der Natur sind. Außerdem können Sie öffentliche Cloud-Dienste verwalten oder Dateien zwischen Ihrem PC und anderen Geräten mit einem Klick synchronisieren.<br \><br \><b>Die Medienzentrale für Datenaustausch und Unterhaltung</b><br \><b>Media Streamer</b><br \>Greifen Sie überall auf die Multimedia-Inhalte auf Ihrem PC zu. Hören Sie auf dem PC gespeicherte Musik, während Sie im Café sitzen, oder zeigen Sie Ihren Freunden Ihren Lieblingsfilm auf einem Smart-TV. Mit ASUS Media Streamer sind Sie überall gut unterhalten.<br \><br \><b>Kabellos in die Zukunft</b><br \><b>NFC EXPRESS 2 &</b><br \><b>Wireless Charger</b><br \>Steuern Sie Ihren PC, und laden Sie Mobilgeräte auf – bequem und kabellos mit NFC Express 2 und Wireless Charger! Steuern Sie den PC durch Antippen, oder legen Sie Ihr Mobilgerät ab, um es wie von Zauberhand aufzuladen. Kabel sind einfach hoffnungslos überholt.<br \><br \><b>Bewährte Qualität. Dauerhaftes Vertrauen.</b><br \><b>Strenge Kompatibilitäts- und Prüfanforderungen</b><br \>Wir sind der größte Mainboard-Hersteller der Welt und bekannt dafür, unsere Produkte auf Benutzer auszurichten – auf Sie. Unsere Ingenieure orientieren sich an strengen Vorgaben, um die Qualität unserer Produkte während ihrer gesamten Lebensdauer zu gewährleisten, und verwenden für die Serienproduktion nur ausgewählte Bauteile. Unsere Mainboards haben ihre Kompatibilität mit mehr als 1.000 Komponenten und Geräten unter Beweis gestellt und mindestens 7.000 Prüfstunden absolviert. Sie können also sicher sein, dass ASUS-Mainboards für alle Umgebungen und Anwendungen geeignet sind. Wenn Sie die besten Komponenten für Ihren PC auswählen möchten, vertrauen Sie auf ein Mainboard von ASUS.<br \><br \><b>Der PC-Eigenbau war noch nie so einfach</b><br \>Wir wissen, wie Sie Ihren PC montieren und nutzen. Deshalb machen wir Ihnen das Leben leichter – von der Montage über Systemeinrichtung und Monitoring bis hin zu Firmware- und Hardware-Updates. Und deshalb suchen wir stets nach neuen und interessanten Lösungen, damit der PC-Eigenbau einfach und unkompliziert ist und Spaß macht.<br \><br \><b>Intel CPU und Chipsatz-Features</b><br \><b>Intel® LGA 1150, 4. Generation, bereit für die 4. und 5. Generation der Prozessoren Core™ i7/Core™ i5/Core™ i3/Pentium®/Celeron®</b><br \>Das Mainboard unterstützt die 4. und 5. Generation der Intel®-Prozessoren Core™ i7/i5/i3/Pentium®/Celeron® mit dem Sockel LGA 1150 und integrierten iGPU-, Speicher- und PCI-Express-Controllern. Unterstützt werden ferner im Prozessor integrierte Grafiklösungen, 2-Kanal-DDR3-Speicher und 16 PCI-Express-3.0/2.0-Lanes. Damit ist eine überragende Grafikleistung garantiert.<br \><br \><b>Intel® Z97 Express-Chipsatz</b><br \>Der Intel® Z97 Express-Chipsatz unterstützt die 4. Generation der Intel®-Prozessoren mit Sockel LGA1150 (Core™ i7/i5/i3/Pentium®/Celeron®). Durch serielle Punkt-zu-Punkt-Verbindungen erzielt der Chipsatz eine höhere Bandbreite und Stabilität und damit eine verbesserte Leistung. Der Z97 bietet bis zu 6 USB-3.0-Anschlüsse, 6 SATA-Anschlüsse mit 6 Gbit/s und Unterstützung für M.2 mit 10 Gbit/s für schnellen Datenabruf. Der Intel® Z97 Express-Chipsatz unterstützt ferner iGPU, sodass integrierte Grafikprozessoren von Intel genutzt werden können.<br \><br \><b>Intel® Smart Response-Technologie</b><br \><b>SSD-Geschwindigkeit mit HDD-Kapazität</b><br \>Ein SSD-Laufwerk (mit mindestens 18,6 GB an freiem Speicherplatz) dient hierbei als Pufferspeicher für Daten, auf die häufig zugegriffen wird. Die wesentlichen Vorteile liegen in verkürzten Ladezeiten und einem geringeren Stromverbrauch, da die (mechanische) Festplatte weniger stark beansprucht wird. Diese Technologie verbindet die Geschwindigkeit von SSD-Laufwerken mit der Kapazität herkömmlicher Festplatten und steigert so die Leistung um das bis zu 6-Fache.<br \><br \><b>Intel® Smart Connect-Technologie</b><br \><b>Automatischer Datenabruf im Ruhezustand für verkürzte Wartezeiten</b><br \>Damit kann Ihr Computer für bestimmte Anwendungen Daten aus dem Internet abrufen, auch wenn das System im Ruhezustand ist. Das bedeutet eine geringere Wartezeit zum Beispiel bei der Synchronisierung mit der Cloud und eine effizientere Nutzung des PC.<br \><br \><b>Intel® Rapid Start-Technologie Sofortige Aktivierung des PC aus dem Ruhezustand</b><br \>Damit kann Ihr Computer in wenigen Sekunden aus dem Ruhezustand aktiviert werden. Indem der Systemspeicher auf einem SSD-Laufwerk gespeichert wird, ist der PC schneller wieder betriebsbereit und spart dennoch Strom.<br \><br \><table><tr><td>ACPI-Version:</td><td>5.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Anzahl DVI-D Anschlüsse:</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Anzahl Ethernet LAN (RJ-45) Anschlüsse:</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Anzahl HDMI Anschlüsse:</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Anzahl PS/2 Anschlüsse:</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Anzahl USB 2.0 Anschlüsse:</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Anzahl USB 2.0 Schnittstellen:</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Anzahl USB 3.0 Anschlüsse:</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Anzahl VGA (D-Sub) Anschlüsse:</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Arbeitsspeicher Typ:</td><td>DIMM</td></tr>
<tr><td>ATX Stromstecker (24-pol.):</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>Audio Chip:</td><td>HDA</td></tr>
<tr><td>Audio Kanäle:</td><td>7.1</td></tr>
<tr><td>BIOS-Speichergröße:</td><td>64 MB</td></tr>
<tr><td>BIOS-Typ:</td><td>UEFI AMI</td></tr>
<tr><td>Breite:</td><td>30,5 cm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Clear CMOS-Jumper:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>CPU Ventilatorstecker:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>Eingebauter Ethernet-Anschluss:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>EPS Stromstecker (8-pin):</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>Ethernet Schnittstellen Typ:</td><td>Gigabit</td></tr>
<tr><td>EZ Stecker:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>Front Panel Audiostecker:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>HDD Schnittstellen:</td><td>Serial ATA III</td></tr>
<tr><td>Kompatible Prozessoren:</td><td>Celeron, Core i3, Core i5, Core i7, Pentium</td></tr>
<tr><td>Komponente für:</td><td>PC</td></tr>
<tr><td>Kopfhörerausgänge:</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>LAN-Controller:</td><td>Intel I218V</td></tr>
<tr><td>Mikrofon, Line-In Anschluss:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>Motherboard Chipsatz:</td><td>Intel Z97</td></tr>
<tr><td>Motherboard Chipsatz Familie:</td><td>Intel</td></tr>
<tr><td>Motherboardformfaktor:</td><td>ATX</td></tr>
<tr><td>Ohne ECC:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>Parallele Verarbeitungstechnologie:</td><td>Quad-GPU CrossFireX, Quad-GPU SLI</td></tr>
<tr><td>PCI-Express x1 (Gen 2.x)-Anschlüsse:</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>PCI-Express x16 (Gen 2.x)-Anschlüsse:</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>PCI-Express x16 (Gen 3.x)-Anschlüsse:</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Prozessorfamilie:</td><td>Intel</td></tr>
<tr><td>Prozessorsockel:</td><td>Socket H3 (LGA 1150)</td></tr>
<tr><td>RAID Level:</td><td>0, 1, 5, 10</td></tr>
<tr><td>RAM-Speicher:</td><td>32 GB</td></tr>
<tr><td>S/PDIF aus Stecker:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>S/PDIF-out Anschluss:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>SATA Anschlüsse:</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>SATA III Anschlüsse:</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Speicherkanäle:</td><td>doppelt/Dual</td></tr>
<tr><td>Speichersteckplätze:</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Tiefe:</td><td>24,4 cm</td></tr>
<tr><td>TPM-Verbinder:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>Unbuffered Speicher:</td><td>Ja</td></tr>
<tr><td>Unterstützte Arbeitsspeicher:</td><td>DDR3-SDRAM</td></tr>
<tr><td>Unterstützte Arbeitsspeichergeschwindigkeit:</td><td>1333, 1600, 1866, 2000, 2133, 2200, 2400, 2600, 2666, 2800, 2933, 3000 MHz</td></tr>
<tr><td>USB 3.0-Anschlüsse:</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Zahl der Chassisventilatorstecker:</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Zahl der EATX Energie Stecker:</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to to split this description and implement the artikel atributes, into an sql table. In the Description the atributes are inside the table.
So that I later can implement a filter on my webpage

I am trying with the following script

```
Create TABLE #test(
[cArtNr] varchar(10),
attribute varchar(100),
Value varchar(100)
)  

DECLARE @S varchar(max),
  @Split char(1),
  @Split2 char(1),
  @Split3 char(1),
  @y varchar(max),
  @X xml,
  @Z int = 1,
  @1 varchar(10),
  @2 varchar(10),
  @3 varchar(10),
  @4 float;

 /*  ### Select Description string and cut everything outside from table tags ### */
SELECT @S = (SELECT 
      [cBeschreibung]
  FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tartikel]
  where cArtNr = 'TF90062750')
  Select @S
  Select @S = RIGHT(@S,LEN(@S)-CHARINDEX('<table>',@S)-6)
  Select @S = LEFT(@S,CHARINDEX('</table>',@S)-1)
  SELECT @S

  /* ### Split Variables ### */
Select @Split = '</td></tr>',
  @Split2 = '</td><td>',
  @Split3 = '<tr><td>'

--Select @S = Replace(@S,@Split2,'</s><s>')
Select @y = Replace(@S,@Split3,'')
SELECT @x = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@y,@Split,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')
Select @x

DECLARE calc3 SCROLL Cursor FOR
SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
SET @3 = 'TF90062750';
OPEN calc3;
FETCH NEXT FROM calc3;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            FETCH NEXT FROM calc3;
            FETCH PRIOR FROM calc3
            INTO @1

            FETCH NEXT FROM calc3
            INTO @2

            Insert into #test ([cArtNr],attribute,Value)
            Values (@3, @1, @2);
            FETCH NEXT FROM calc3;
        END
DEALLOCATE calc3;

Select * from #test
```

I am somehow stuck, I would appreciate a little help
Please let me know if you would choose another approach and how it is done.

My result is like and this seems false

```
TF90062750  /s>s>tr>/s  NULL
TF90062750  tr>td>ACPI  NULL
TF90062750  tr>td>ACPI  NULL
```

Comment: so exactly how is your sql code not working for you?

Comment: @edited  it is only implementing one value and the values its implementing are wrong

Comment: Which database version(s) do you have available?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 r2